# What resistor could I replace this broken one with?

Tags: resistors, identification, component-values

Can anyone help decipher what resistor this is? R1 - I am struggling to figure out what the resistor is as it is blown and the colour bands are burnt:

[image]

[image]

Circuit board has written on it

- 0L-A011-POWER-PLUS
- 20200103 VER:1.0
- KB-5150 E123995

It’s the power supply/control board out of a Homecom 823-010V72 air conditioner.

Additional photos of circuit top, bottom, blended and some symbols:

[image: Front View]

[image: Back View]

[image: Mixed View]

[image: With symbols]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142216/discussion-on-question-by-paulf-what-resistor-could-i-replace-this-broken-one-wi).

Comment: Chat between my self and peter here with more information: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142204/discussion-between-peter-jennings-and-paulf

Answer (score 6):

I have the same board in a Meaco air con about to repair. My resistor's colours are red red black gold black and on a meter it measures 22 ohms.

Answer (score 1):

A grey resistor with a black band is almost certainly a wirewound resistor used as a fuse.

Looks like maybe red-violet-black-gold (27 Ω)?

Nonetheless, like any other fuse that exploded, something else on your board failed and drew too much current. Replacing this resistor with a similar part will likely burn it up in a similar fashion. Replacing it with a higher-wattage part is not a good idea and may result in something else exploding in a more spectacular fashion.

Comment: There is already a wired in fuse on the board on the mains side of the common mode choke. So the resistor is most likely inrush protection. See the discussion in the chat room for more photos. And look at the circuit diagram in the data sheet.

Answer (score -2):

Looking at your photo it may not be a crispy critter but definitely got overheated. I would measure the resistance and if reasonable purchase another one with maybe 2X the wattage rating of the one there. If it is blown contact the factory to see if you can get a schematic. If possible see if you can find another unit and take a picture, be sure to note the colors. Of course you could purchase a replacement.

Comment: This is likely a fusible wirewound resistor. Replacing a fuse part with one of higher wattage is not a good idea.

Comment: See my comments to Gil's answer. Replacing a fusible resistor with one of double the wattage is as bad as replacing an ordinary fuse with a copper nail - **don't do it!**. You are just creating a bigger hazzard. That resistor burnt out for a reason, some other fault which needs fixing first.

Comment: How do you know for sure it is a fusible resistor? It appears to me as a surge resistor with a seperate fuse. No other indications on the board I see to indicate otherwise.

Comment: It's strange that they used a proper fuse for some other part of the board (relay outputs) but chose a hopefully fusible resistor for what looks like a flyback aux power supply. Inrush issues? Fault current on the flyback not high enough to safely burn the real fuse open?